# Is this an example of the third person?

Tags: semantics

Suppose Alice says to Bob, "I cook dinner with Bob." Is Alice talking about Bob in the third person?

Comment: Your example is a bad one. Why would she say this to Bob? _I cook dinner with Paul_ is what she could say to Bob. Better is to not mention who she said it to.

Comment: To clarify, Alice is referring to the same Bob; Alice means "I cook dinner with you".

Comment: _You_ is second person. That's why she wouldn't say it to Bob; while he's the addressee, _you_ is used. When she's talking to somebody else, like on the phone, even if he's still in the room, she can say that and it's third person, because it's **referential** -- it refers to something or someone. First and second persons are **deictic** -- their reference depends on the current context only and can change with the context.

Answer (score 0):

Grammatically, yes *Bob* is third person. Hence even if Alice is speaking to Bob, then he will interpret her sentence as referring to some other person named Bob.

Comment: Unless you're addressing somebody by name (_Say, Bob, are you coming over tonight?_), all English nouns are third person. All pronouns except _I, you,_ and _we_ are also third person.